# How can a final-job-to-be-displayed in a Jenkins Delivery Pipeline view be configured using the Job DSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, delivery-pipeline

### The setup

- We're using the Jenkins Delivery Pipeline Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin)
- We're also using the Job DSL Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)

### How to do it through the UI

On the *View* configuration page, there's a setting for the last displayed job in the *view*:

```
Pipelines
  Components
    Name                    [text field here]
    Initial Job             [text field here]
    Final Job (optional)    [text field here]
```

When a *final Job* is given, the the view does not display any jobs that may be triggered by that job, i.e. as the label implies, this job is the last job displayed in this view.

### The question

How can I configure this final job name, using the Job DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the last job is currently not supported by the built-in DSL. But you can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to generate any configuration:

```
deliveryPipelineView('example') {
  pipelines {
    component('one', 'foo1')
    component('two', 'foo2')
  }
  configure { view ->
    def components = view / componentSpecs
    components.'se.diabol.jenkins.pipeline.DeliveryPipelineView_-ComponentSpec'[0] << lastJob('bar1')
    components.'se.diabol.jenkins.pipeline.DeliveryPipelineView_-ComponentSpec'[1] << lastJob('bar2')
  }
}
```